# At most one LocalDate per month in a list

Tags: java, guava, jodatime

I'm implementing argument check in a method where one parameter is a `List` of `LocalDate` objects (from [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)). I want to make sure that `List` contains **at most one `LocalDate` per month**.

```
public List<LocalDate> generateAllDates(List<LocalDate> firstYearDates, ...) { }
```

Thus, for example

```
Arrays.asList(
    new LocalDate(2012, 3, 25),
    new LocalDate(2012, 4, 30),
    new LocalDate(2013, 3, 26)
)
```

would be an illegal argument because there are *two dates whose month is March*.

Currently I have something like this (making use of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s Multimap):

```
Multimap<Integer, LocalDate> monthToDates = HashMultimap.create();
for (LocalDate date : firstYearDates) {
    monthToDates.put(date.getMonthOfYear(), date);
}
for (Integer i : monthToDates.keySet()) {
    if (monthToDates.get(i).size() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "firstYearDates must contain at most one entry per month");
    }
}
```

Question is, **how would you simplify that**? Using any API features of JDK 1.6, Guava or Joda-Time is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit late but there is Guava built-in method for that - [Maps.uniqueIndex](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) - given:

```
List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList(
     new LocalDate(2012,3,25), new LocalDate(2012,4,30), new LocalDate(2013,3,26);
```

with JDK 8:

```
Maps.uniqueIndex(dates, LocalDate::getMonthOfYear);
```

or with JDK <7:

```
Maps.uniqueIndex(dates, new Function<LocalDate, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(final LocalDate date) {
      return date.getMonthOfYear();
    }
});
```

It will throw

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: 3
```

in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you only need to know if a month has been found before or not. I wouldn't then go through the trouble of using a Multimap if there is no other reason for it.

```
boolean[] monthFound = new boolean[12];
for(LocalDate date : firstYearDates) {
  if(monthFound[date.getMonthOfYear() - 1]) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "firstYearDates must contain at most one entry per month");
  } else {
     monthFound[date.getMonthOfYear() - 1] = true;
  }
}
```

If you need the map then just check `containsKey(month)` before each `put` and throw an exception if the method returns true.

If you just want to use Guava then one way of doing this might be

```
Function<LocalDate, Integer> months = new Function<LocalDate, Integer>() {    
      public Integer apply(LocalDate date) { return date.getMonthOfYear(); }
};

if(new HashSet(Collections2.transform(firstYearDates, months)).size() < firstYearDates.size()) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "firstYearDates must contain at most one entry per month");
}
```

Comment: +1. I guess I sometimes get carried away by Guava's fancy data structures and become blind to plain old Java options like boolean arrays. Good point about containsKey too. If fact, I'll probably use a plain map and containsKey, as I'm not a fan of array indexing minutiae [ `date.getMonthOfYear() - 1` ] if it can be avoided.

Comment: You can create a 13 element array if you are not starving for memory :) You could also use bit arrays if you want to go old school.